# In my project sub folders are viewable. I need to make it forbidden. How shall i make it?

Tags: .htaccess

For example, if i give the below url in the address bar all images are viewable right now.

URL : http:///www.test.com/images/

How shall i able to avoid this.. It should not be viewable or it should be restricted or redirected to some other page.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it by using

**Options -Indexes**

which should be entered in .htaccess file and should be placed inside the corresponding folder.

And its working fine now...